# Unable to convert seconds to HH:MM:SS

Tags: javascript

While trying to convert seconds into HH:MM:SS seconds format, I am getting the incorrect result. For example, if take value of `seconds` be `289` the minutes come out as `0`. What could be the reason for this

```
var seconds = this.currentTime;
var hours = Math.floor(seconds/3600); // Get whole hours
seconds -= hours*3600;

var minutes = Math.floor(seconds/3600); // Get remaining minutes
console.log("minutes : " + minutes);
seconds -= minutes*60;

var timeNow = hours + ":" + (minutes<10 ? '0'+minutes : minutes) + ":" + (seconds<10 ? '0'+seconds : seconds);
```

Comment: You aren't including all the code.  What is `this.currentTime`?

Comment: Have you considered using a library like Moment.js? http://momentjs.com/docs/

Comment: @Chrissi seconds `289.143188`

Comment: @SuhailGupta Where did you get `this.currentTime` from?  Did you use a library?  What is the purpose of this code and what does `this.currentTime` represent?  I don't know what 289.143188 means.

Comment: @Chrissi How does that matter?

Comment: @SuhailGupta Well, I wasn't sure what `this.currentTime` represented.  I think I see now that it's an arbitrary number of seconds.  Without knowing what it was, I wasn't sure if your assignment of `var seconds = this.currentTime;` was an accurate assignment.  If `this.currentTime` does not represent an arbitrary number of seconds, it could cause problems.   But it seems your problem has been solved :) So no worries!

Comment: @SuhailGupta it would have mattered because in JS time is usually measured in milliseconds, not seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To calculate minutes, you should divide seconds by 60, not 3600 (there are 60 seconds in a minute after all):

```
var minutes = Math.floor(seconds/60); // Get remaining minutes
```

You could also use the `Date` object in JavaScript to do most of this for you:

```
var date = new Date(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 289, 0);
var minutes = date.getMinutes();
// etc.
```

Comment: Oh! Thank you for spotting that.

Answer (score 1):

```
var timeInSec = this.currentTime;
var hours = Math.floor(timeInSec / 3600) % 24; // Get whole hours
var minutes = Math.floor(timeInSec / 60) % 60; // Get remaining minutes
var seconds = timeInSec % 60; // Get remaining seconds
var timeNow = (hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours) + "-" + (minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes) + "-" + (seconds  < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds);
```

Comment: down voted for using `parseInt` as a rounding function.